# Anorm says no results were returned for select query preceded by inserts (PSQLException: No results were returned by the query)

Tags: postgresql, scala, anorm

I'm writing a Play 2 application with a Postgres backend.

My code has a sql string which is a concatenation of two inserts and a select. Then when I try to execute my query, anorm blows up and says me no results have been returned. I could break it up into two separate queries but then I'd be making an unnecessary trip to the database?

The sql string is pretty simple.

```
val sql = """
        insert into gameconstants 
            ...
        values 
            ...;

        insert into gamevariables
            ...
        values
            ...;

        select lastval() as gameid;
  """
```

Then the code that throws the exception just tries to get the gameid from query. This should work right?

```
DB.withTransaction { implicit connection =>
  val gameid = SQL(sql).on(
    ... )()
    .map(row => row[Long]("gameid")).head
}
```

Here is the error **[PSQLException: No results were returned by the query.]**

Comment: You'll be making the trips to the DB anyway. PgJDBC will split your composite statement up and send the individual statements. Watch the network traffic or PgJDBC debug logs to see the details.

Comment: So the preferred way to do this is actually to send multiple statements over the network? Isn't this some low hanging fruit?

Comment: The proper way to do it is to create a JDBC batch and send the batch. Last time I checked PgJDBC's batching support landed up just sending each query separately anyway, but this may've changed more recently. Yes, it'd be great to improve, but for all the people using PgJDBC almost nobody ever contributes to it.

Comment: @Mark Maybe you should create a stored procedure for this. That would reduce the network usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the other comments have said, this is caused by issuing a composite statement to JDBC.  You have a couple options.

1. You could do a JDBC batch.  As Craig notes above this just sends each query separately in a batch.
2. You could write a user defined function/stored procedure with this logic and call in a single query.  This has the advantage of encapsulating your db logic behind an API.  The disadvantage is that without a lot of attention it becomes hard to maintain contracts between stored procedures and the application.  This is an area I am doing some work on in Perl, but not yet getting there in Java.
3. You could collapse the query into two (your code shows three).  The simple solution is:

   ```
   val query1 = """
       insert into gameconstants 
           ...
       values 
           ...;"""


   val query2 = """
       insert into gamevariables
           ...
       values
           ...
       RETURNING * 
    """
   ```

This would reduce your round trips to some extent.